# ajax - no ! after # - do the crawlers read this?

Tags: ajax, seo

I made a site - all requests are sent to server via AJAX, but there is no ! afer # so it wont be changed by crawlers on ?_escaped_fragment_. Everytime you click on link on my site all you do is changing name after #. Then request to server is send - php is querying mysql for data and then json with this data comes back- its recognized and the content (DOM and text) changes.

in short way - all links just ASK for data from mysql. There is no html or anything

You can add this links and it works.
You can go forward and backward it works.

The Question:

Do the crawlers index my link and json data which comes from it ?

Answer (score 0):

The content AJAX is not indexed for google. 
You will have to add tags < noscript > if you want add some static content and will be indexed for the crawler.

There are more elegant solution as you comment, building the ajax links as for example twitter did.

Anyway you will need the parameter ! after # if you want that the crawler will translate the url.

For example if you follow my next link you will see my twitter page, but see the parameters in the link:
https://twitter.com/#!MuSTa1nE

For the crawler is translate as:
http://twitter.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/MuSTa1nE

You don´t want that google index the ugly url so remember to do a 301 redirect.

Review the next content:
http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content

Expect it will be helpful.

Comment: Not quite right. Google has to index the _escaped_fragment_ URL to find what the page is about. Google knows that it should feed the non _escaped_fragment_ version to users.

Comment: Google have not to index the escaped_fragment have to index the page that you want to be index, for that the redirect 301 for the pretty url